# maven exclude files when creating zip

Tags: maven, zip

We have a separate module for configurations and properties. We create a zip of this package. Now there are certain files which we want to exclude from our zip file. How can i do that, i tried the excludes tag but it does not works, below is our assembly.xml file

```
<id>zip-config</id>
<baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <outputDirectory>project-config</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>src/main/resources/*.sh</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Comment: Just try `<exclude>*.sh</exclude>`....

Answer (score 0):

Is seems that it worked with `<exclude>**/*.sh</exclude>`.

Comment: *seems* seems not to be very reliable as an answer to me... some explanation? thanks!